# Add button to symfony easyadmin TextField

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I want to add a button next to a TextField in the create/update page of the CRUD controller in order to generate a random string I can use as a token. I tried to do this by using `setFormTypeOptions` as explained in the [symfony](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/design.html#form-field-templates) docs. But instead of including (adding) the button, it replaces the whole form type and the textbox is gone.

Is it possible to add a button without copying the template from the easyadmin folder?

Comment: I guess the simple solution would be to create a custom TextField (by creating a custom easy admin field) that include in its template a button that trigger some js to generate a random string